# Reshaping a commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, xymatrix

I have this diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,color]{xy}

\begin{document}

$$
&&\xymatrix{
&&&&&X\times Y\times Z\times T\ar[ld]\ar[rd]\ar[ld]\ar[lllldd]\ar[rrrrdd]&&&&&\\
&&&&X\times Y\times T\ar[rd]\ar[rrrrrdd]\ar[lllldd]&&X\times Z\times T\ar[ld]\ar[llllldd]\ar[rrrrdd]&&&&\\
&X\times Y\times Z\ar[ld]\ar[d]\ar[rrrrd]&&&&X\times T&&&&Y\times Z\times T\ar[lllld]\ar[d]\ar[rd]&\\
X\times Y&X\times Z&&&&Y\times Z&&&&Y\times T&Z\times T\\
}
$$

\end{document}
```

And I have an issue: the first one is that the diagram doesn't fit the page, and the right side of the page won't display in the created pdf. Besides, I want to color some specific arrow.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! Please edit your MWE : put four spaces at the beginning of each line and, above all, make it fully compiliable. A simple copy paste should be sufficient, we should'nt have to add a preamble, especially since you are using custom package.

Comment: thanks @sztruks for the comment. Do you mean I should add some `\usepackage{ xymatrix}` ?

Comment: Yes you should, and all the `documentclass`, `begin{document}` lines and so on.

Comment: @sztruks ok I added the right header. Thanks for help

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use bending arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,color]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@C-2.5pc@R+2pc{
  &&&&&X\times Y\times Z\times T\ar[ld] \ar@[red][rd]
    \ar@/_3pc/[lllldd]\ar@/^3pc/[rrrrdd]&&&&&\\
  &&&&X\times Y\times T\ar[rd]\ar@/^1pc/[rrrrrdd]\ar@/_3pc/[lllldd]&&
    X\times Z\times T\ar[ld]\ar@/_1pc/[llllldd]\ar@/^3pc/[rrrrdd]&&&&\\
  &X\times Y\times Z\ar[ld]\ar[d]\ar[rrrrd]&&&&X\times T&&&&
    Y\times Z\times T\ar[lllld]\ar[d]\ar@[red][rd]&\\
  X\times Y&X\times Z&&&&Y\times Z&&&&Y\times T&Z\times T
}
\]

\end{document}
```

I also colored a couple of arrows, just to show how it can be done.

I removed the duplicate `\ar[ld]` from the first row.

[image]

Similarly, with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-0.6em,row sep=huge]
&&& X\times Y\times Z\times T\arrow[ld] \arrow[rd,color=red]
    \arrow[lldd,bend right=40] \arrow[rrdd,bend left=40]
\\
&& X\times Y\times T \arrow[rd] \arrow[lldd,bend right=40] \arrow[rrrdd,bend left]
&& X\times Z\times T \arrow[ld] \arrow[llldd,bend right] \arrow[rrdd,bend left=40]
\\
& X\times Y\times Z \arrow[ld] \arrow[d] \ar[rrd]
&& X\times T
&& Y\times Z\times T\arrow[lld] \arrow[d] \arrow[rd,color=red]
\\
X\times Y & X\times Z && Y\times Z && Y\times T& Z\times T
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user2478159 You're welcome. I added the `tikz-cd` version. You have a duplicate `\ar[ld]` arrow in your code (first row). Never use `$$` in LaTeX.